# What is the maximum number of inputs for any logic gate?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, digital-logic

In the references that we use, I usually see either a 2 or 3-input logic gate. Four-input gates come by once in a while. However, is there a certain limit to the number of inputs a logic gate can have theoretically? I'm assuming in actual practice there is some sort of limit due to the increased complexity as number of input increases. But just hypothetically, are we limited to 4 (because that's the maximum I ever saw in a text by far)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of gate inputs is limited due to electrical constraints. It depends on the technology being used.

**For example:**

A CMOS NAND with three inputs has three transistors connected in series

[image: static CMOS NAND with three inputs]

The more inputs, the higher the resistance to draw the NAND output from high to low.

Practical circuit designs strive to either minimize the number of components, the switching latency or the silicon die area.

For a high number of inputs, gates are typically composed of several smaller gates.

**Example:**
AND5 realized as NAND3 + NAND2 + NOR2

[image]

Comment: "The more inputs, the higher the resistance to draw the NAND output from high to low."

@Axel Kemper, could you please elaborate on this further? I don't fully understand how this is so.

TIA

Comment: To change output Y from high to low, the three transistors have to conduct electrical current. Their sum of internal resistances determines the time needed to unload the output capacitance. A circuit with three transistors in series needs longer than a circuit with just two transistors. Therefore, the number of inputs has an increasing impact on the latency for a falling edge at the gate output.

Answer (score 0):

In an idealized physical world, in pure logic, or in boolean algebra, there is no limit to the number of inputs to an AND/NAND gate or to an OR/NOR gate, just as there is no limit to the number of variables over which an boolean AND or OR function can be applied.

There is no defined output value for an exclusive-OR gate with other than 2 inputs, nor for an inverter/negator with other than 1 input.